# Extract subset of SalesForce table filtered by a daily dynamic date with azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, soql

I need to extract daily data from a SalesForce table, then output it as a JSON file in order to send it to an other server everyday.

I wonder if it's possible to do this with Azure Data Factory. Currently, I've seen a static way of doing it with this type a request :

```
  $$Text.Format('SELECT * FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >= {{ts\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}\'}} AND LastModifiedDate < {{ts\'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}\'}}', WindowStart, WindowEnd)
```

I can't find a way to have WindowStart and WindowEnd to be dynamic (because I want all rows concerning only the previous day).

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. Can you please consult with the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-read-write-partitioned-data) and refine your question? The WindowStart/End parameters **are** dynamic - they represent the times for a concrete activity / data slice.

Comment: Thank you for the github link, it was the information I needed. My solution was to use Date.AddDays(WindowStart, -1).